# Model Binding of List<string> Fails with List of One Element

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, model-binding

I have code that passes a List or strings to a Controller Action which works perfectly as long as there are 2 or more items in the List.  If there is a single item in the list, the parameter of the Controller resolves to null (a result of model binding failure, I presume).

For example, if my Controller Action has a signature such as

```
public ActionResult myAction(List<string> myList)
```

And I have a Uri such as

```
someUri?mylist=first&mylist=second&mylist=third
```

works just fine, but with a Uri such as

```
someurl?mylist=first
```

the parameter myList resolves to null.  Do I have to append a blank value as a second item in the list or is there some other way to force the model binder to correctly bind?

Update, here are some literal values:

```
public void PDFOutput(Guid MyProtocolsId, List<string> AssociationTypes)
```

This works:

```
http://localhost:50024/MyProtocols/FullPrint/642ff9cd-fb32-4a79-aaa4-088278796bb0?AssociationsTypes=Problem&AssociationTypes=Goal&AssociationTypes=StandardOrder&AssociationTypes=Outcome
```

This doesn't:

```
http://localhost:50024/MyProtocols/FullPrint/642ff9cd-fb32-4a79-aaa4-088278796bb0?AssociationsTypes=Problem
```

RouteConfig:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyProtocols",
            url: "MyProtocols/{action}/{myProtocolsId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyProtocols", action = "Index", myProtocolsId = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this, what version of ASP.NET MVC are you using? You're going to have to give more detail I'm afraid.

Comment: I am targeting .NET Framework 4.7.2

Comment: But MVC5? MVC Core? Give us **more details**!

Comment: MVC 5 (not Core)

Comment: I've added some literal values to the original post.

Comment: how you do the redirection, if you do it with form, the parameters will be sent in the body of the page and not in the url

Comment: What is your routing config to get this working?

Comment: RouteConfig updated in original post

Comment: @LPGTE.SOFTS In this case it is a GET request.  I just tested using POST it is works fine.  Unfortunately, I have to use the GET method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dealing with list you can pass list objects using index as query string like below.

```
http://localhost:50024/MyProtocols/FullPrint/642ff9cd-fb32-4a79-aaa4-088278796bb0?[0]=Problem
```

I have tried and it is working as below.
[image]

Comment: While I'm not thrilled that the model binder can't deal with a single value List without this sort of syntax, this does work and has solved my problem.  Thanks all for the input.